# Symfony 4 twig doctrine, Associating submenu to dropdown list

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I am currently doing a site under symfony. In the nav, I call with twig the content of my database with this  [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62tLP.png).
Here the code:

```
{% for advert in listWorker %}
{% if advert.client != 'xxxxx' %}
<li class="sidebar-dropdown">
    <a href="#">
        <span>{{ advert.client }}</span>
    </a>
    <div class="sidebar-submenu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">{{ advert.nom }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, I would like the result to appear like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcOXx.png) and i really don't know how to associate names with the same clients in the same list...

here is my [controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1mmO.png)

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of what $worker->findAll() returns, it would help.

Comment: are you using a ui framework, like bootstrap? if so which version?

Comment: Please don't post code as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lacking the original data from your $worker->findAll(), here is an example with some dummy data that symfony could return :

```
$db = array(
    '1' => array(
        'client1' => 'name1'
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'client1' => 'name2'
    ),
    '3' => array(
        'client2' => 'name1'
    ),
    '4' => array(
        'client2' => 'name2'
    ),
    '5' => array(
        'client2' => 'name3'
    ),
    '6' => array(
        'client3' => 'name1'
    ),
    '7' => array(
        'client1' => 'name2'
    )
);
```

**Then you could create a new array that will regroup everything by client :**

```
$final = [];

foreach($db as $item)
{
    $key = key($item);
    $final[$key][] = $item[$key];
}
```

**How this array will look :**

```
array(3) {
  ["client1"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "name1"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "name2"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "name2"
  }
  ["client2"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "name1"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "name2"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "name3"
  }
  ["client3"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "name1"
  }
}
```

Pass it to your index.html.twig view and iterate over it.
Some reading material: [twig nested loop](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/recipes.html#accessing-the-parent-context-in-nested-loops)

Comment: Your link to nested loop was the thing i was looking for at the end , now it work perfectly.